# Is there any faster way to perform merge on 120k records weekly in oracle pl/sql?

Tags: oracle, function, stored-procedures, plsql, procedure

There are around 120k records in the database, and based on a few functions I calculate scores for all the records, weekly I have to update the table with new records and respective scores.

Below is a procedure that I am using to merge data into the table:

```
create or replace procedure scorecalc
AS
score1 number;
score2 number;
score3 number;
CURSOR cur IS
 SELECT Id_number from tableA;

        r_num cur%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  --OPEN cur;
  FOR r_num IN cur
  LOOP
    select functionA(r_num.id_number),functionb(r_num.id_number),functionc(r_num.id_number)  into score1, score2,score3 from dual;
Merge into scores A USING
(Select
 r_num.id_number as ID, score1 as scorea, score2 as scoreb, score3 as scorec, TO_DATE(sysdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as scoredate
FROM DUAL) B
ON ( A.ID = B.ID and A.scoredate = B.scoredate)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (
 ID, scorea, scoreb, scorec, scoredate)
VALUES (
 B.ID, B.scorea, B.scoreb, B.scorec,B.scoredate)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET
 A.scorea = B.scorea,
 A.scoreb = B.scoreb,
 A.scorec = B.scorec;
 COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

whereas functionA/ B/ C has complex queries, joins in it to calculate the score.

Please suggest me any way to improve the performance because currently with this snippet of code I am only able to insert some 2k records in 1 hour? Can I use parallel DML here? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing this in a procedure?  This could all be done via DML:

```sql
MERGE INTO scores a USING
  (SELECT ta.id_number AS ID, 
          functionA(ta.id) AS scoreA,
          functionB(ta.id) AS scoreB,
          functionC(ta.id) AS scoreC,
          TO_DATE(sysdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as scoredate
   FROM tableA ta) b
ON (a.id = b.id AND a.scoredate = b.scoredate)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
  a.scorea = b.scorea,
  a.scoreb = b.scoreb,
  a.scorec = b.scorec
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (ID, scorea, scoreb, scorec, scoredate)
VALUES (B.ID, B.scorea, B.scoreb, B.scorec,B.scoredate);
```

If you want to try using `PARALLEL` hint after that, feel free.  But you should definitely get rid of that cursor and stop doing "Slow-by-slow" processing.

Comment: I am doing this in the procedure because I need to schedule it for every Sunday night

Comment: @PriyadarshniSagar If you are using `DBMS_SCHEDULER` just wrap the DML in a simple anonymous block (Just `BEGIN` and `END;`). You can use that as PL/SQL block for your job.

Answer (score 0):

Something I've had some success with has been inserting from a select statement. It is pretty performant as it doesn't involve row by row inserting.

In your case, I'm thinking it would be something like:

```
INSERT INTO table (ID, scorea, scoreb, scorec, scoredate)
SELECT functionA(id_number), functionB(id_number), functionC(id_number)
FROM tableA
```

An example of this can be found at the link below:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems025.htm

Answer (score 0):

To schedule it just put the statement @Del in a procedure block;

```
create or replace procedure Saturday_Night_Merge is 
begin 
    <Put the merge statement here> 
end Saturday_Night_Merge;
```